# Form Textarea Resize Icon/Handle is missing in IE/FF?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with text area and defined resize:both in css.

However, the resize handle / icon is missing on IE and Firefox but visible in Chrome. How can I fix this, or does these browser doen't support it.

Note that I'm using Twitter Bootstrap CSS as my CSS framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [support table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize). No support in IE yet. Support exists in Firefox, and my test just confirmed this—but the handle is a little less noticeable than in Chrome:

[image: Textarea with resize handle on FF]

Perhaps there is something else in your CSS code that overrides the setting, in a manner that affects Chrome but not Firefox.

Comment: Have a look at the demo for bootstrap, it is also not visible in FF over there.. may be you're right. I have tried to make it visible in FF but don't know why its not working. I also tried to find the styles which might preventing it but unable to find.

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox 14.0.1, the handle disappears when you change the CSS border property on a textarea in any way - color, width, style, whatever. If you leave it as default, then the handle is visible. Could be a bug.